# How to fix the background image in bootstrap 3 for both big and small screen sizes?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, background

My CSS is as follows

```
body {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/mom-bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover ;
    font: 16px "anitypewritermedium";
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just exchange the background `scroll` to `fixed`

```
body {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/mom-bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed 0 0 / cover;
    font: 16px "anitypewritermedium";
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important; 
}
```

online example: http://jsfiddle.net/adaknLw4/

Comment: i did this but the divs moving over background , which i made for some oher purpose having images

Comment: Yeah that's what the `background-image:fixed;` does. That's what you're asking on your question, or at least it's what it seems to be... but apparently by your comment here that's not what you are trying to do. So can you improve your question and be more specific then? Also check out the **[How to ask a good question page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**